# How to call a super constructor in groovy that accepts varargs?

Tags: groovy, polymorphism, variadic-functions

I am using groovy as an extension language in my application. The constructor of the class which a script extend accepts variable arguments. When I try to instantiate the groovy class, I get an java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException from the `super()` call in the constructor. The issue can easily be reproduced in a standalone groovy script:

```
// problem.groovy
class A {
    A(float ... more) {}
}

class B extends A {
    B() {
        super();
    }
}

new B();
```

when run, this produces:

```
$ groovy problem.groovy
Caught: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at B.<init>(problem.groovy:7)
    at problem.run(problem.groovy:11)
```

line 7 is the `super()` call in class `B`.

Is this a bug in the language itself? I couldn't find any other mention of it online. I'm new to Groovy and I may well not be understanding some subtlety of the language. At the very least, it seems like this should throw a compiler error when loading the script.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`@InheritConstructors`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/transform/InheritConstructors.html) AST to avoid this boilerplate code.

```
class A {
    A(float ... more) {}
}

@groovy.transform.InheritConstructors
class B extends A {}

new B()
```

Moreover, in your example wouldn't you provide a default constructor in A (since it is being overloaded) and then use `super()` in B's constructor. Or initialize the overloaded constructors args to `null`.

```
class A {
    A(){println 'default'} 

    //Or use A(float... more = null) {println 'varargs'} 
    //instead of default constructor
    A(float... more) {println 'varargs'}
}

class B extends A {
    B(){
        super()
    }
}

new B() 
//Uses default constructor A() if overloaded 
//constructor is not initialized to null
```

Comment: These are decent solutions. I've taken the second approach of adding a default constructor to the superclass, but it still bugs me that this doesn't work correctly. I'll probably create a Groovy ticket for it, unless someone is aware of an existing discussion/bug slip.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be calling a nonexistent constructor with super()  - call it even with a null or put a no arg constructor in A and it works. 
It appears that the variable arg constructor on the superclass isn't matching. Fun.

Comment: I see there was a discussion on something similar back in 2008 - http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Variable-argument-constructor-td355628.html